# Why does my own implementation of Fast Fourier Transform in N dimensions give different results than NumPy's?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I've written the following code for the N-dimensional Fast Fourier Transform but it doesn't give me the same result as numpy's function.

```
def nffourier(f, direct):
    dim = f.ndim  
    N = f.shape
    G = np.zeros(f.shape, dtype=complex)
    G = f
    
    for k in range(dim):
        for i in range(N[k]):
            aux = G[(slice(None),) * (k) + (i,)]
            trans = ffourier(aux, direct)
            G[(slice(None),) * (k) + (i,)] = trans
            
    return G
```

My code for calculating FFT in 1d is the following:

```
def ffourier(f, direct):
    N = len(f)
    
    M = int(m.log(N)/m.log(2))
        
    G = []
    order = []
    
    for i in range(N):
        order.append(int(bin(i)[2:]))
    
    digitos = len(aux)
    for i in range(N):
        contenido_aux = str(int(order[i]))
        aux = len(str(order[i]))
        if(aux<digitos):
            añadir=digitos-aux
            for k in range(añadir):
                contenido_aux = '0'+contenido_aux
        G.append(contenido_aux)
    for i in range(len(G)):
        G[i] = G[i][::-1]
    

    for i in range(len(G)):
        G[i] = int(G[i], 2)
    for i in range(len(G)):
        G[i] = f[G[i]]
    

    
   
    if direct == False:
        signo = 1
    else:
        signo = -1


    kmax = 1
    kmax = int(kmax)
    for alfa in range(1,M+1):
        w1 = np.exp(signo*1j*2*m.pi/(2**alfa))
        kmax = int(2*kmax)
        W = 1
        for k in range(0, int(kmax/2)-1+1):
            for s in range(0, N-1+1, int(kmax)):
                T0 = G[s+k]
                T1 = G[s+k+int(kmax/2)]*W
                G[s+k]=T0+T1
                G[s+k+int(kmax/2)]=T0-T1
            W=W*w1
    cte = 1/m.sqrt(N)
    for i in range(0, N-1+1):
        G[i] = G[i]*cte 
    return G
```

The fundamentals of it is quite hard to explain, it's based on bit inversion, but I've checked it works properly, so the problem is with the N dimensional code.

Comment: Many of you would answer to use python's default functions, but I need to write these functions myself :)

Comment: When you do `G = f` you assign `f` to the variable `G`, the earlier assignment becomes useless. Instead, do `G = f.astype(complex)`, and leave out the `np.zeros` call.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've already added it... The G=f... is that really a problem? I mean, is that what makes my code not work?

Comment: It turns `G` into a real-valued array.

Comment: I've already made the changed you suggested... Now it gives good results with 2 dimensions, but still doesn't work for 3 dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing `G[(slice(None),) * (k) + (i,)]` works in 2D but not in higher dimensions. Let’s see what it does:

Say `G` is 2D. Now when `k=0`, your indexing is the same as `G[i]`, which is the same as `G[i,:]`. You are selecting rows. When `k=1`, then that indexing is `G[:,i]`. You are selecting columns.

But now say `G` is 3D. Now when `k=0`, you get `G[i]` again, which now is equivalent to `G[i,:,:]`. You are selecting a 2D subarray! What you need is a 1D subarray. You need to get `G[i,j,:]` for all `i` and all `j`. And then `G[i,:,j]`, and then `G[:,i,j]`.

Likewise, for a 5D array, you want `G[i,j,k,l,:]`, etc. That is to say, you want to loop over all dimensions minus one.

To loop over all `i` and `j`, you could do a double loop, but then you have specific 3D code. It is possible to write a loop over an arbitrary number of dimensions, but it’s not pretty. So we’ll look for an alternative.

I think the simplest way to get this to work is to flatten those N-1 dimensions, turning a MxNxOxPxQ array into a 2D (`N*M*O*P`)xQ array. Now you can do a 1D loop over the first dimension.

Now you need to loop over the dimensions, it’s a different dimension that we leave out every time. We can simplify this problem by “rolling” the dimensions, make a different dimension the last one every time, then apply that same flattening code. Now it’s easy to write a loop (not tested):

```py
def nffourier(f, direct):
    dim = f.ndim  
    G = f.astype(complex)
    
    for k in range(dim):
        G = np.moveaxis(G, 0, -1)  # shifts the dimensions by one to the left
        shape = G.shape
        m = shape[-1]
        G = np.reshape(G, (-1, m))  # flattens all but last dimension
        m = G.shape[0]
        for i in range(m):          # loop over first dimension
            G[i, :] = ffourier(G[i, :], direct)  # apply over last dimension
        G = np.reshape(G, shape)    # return to original shape
    
    # After applying moveaxis dim times, G should have the same dimension order it had at the start
    return G
```

(Note also, as we already discussed in the comments, that the `G = f` line causes the output array `G` to be of the same type as `f`, likely not complex, and so will cause errors also.)

Comment: I haven't understood a single thing. What does exactly mean "

Your indexing, G[(slice(None),) * (k) + (i,)], is the same as G[:,:,i,:,:] for a 5D array if k is 2."?

Comment: I reeally don't know how to think it in more than 2 dimensions, but in 2D it would be like, I have to first pick each column (or row), calculate its FFT, and then pick each row (or column) and calculate its FFT

Comment: Isn't here a way of doing this recursively reducing the number of dimensions till 1?

Comment: @elenafer I rewrote the text in the answer, I hope it’s more clear now.

Comment: What does the line G = np.reshape(G, (-1, m))  do? I've commented it and the output doesn't change

Comment: @elenafer It turns the N-1 dimensions into one, so you iterate over it. If N>2 you should see a difference in output without it.